# Function for Multiplying Two 3x3 Matrices

Tags: c++, matrix

I pass 3 matrices to my `multiplyMatrix` function. Matrices `a` and `b` are entered by the user, and `c` is the product of `a` and `b`. I am getting an error when assigning values to `c`.

> expression must be a modifiable Ivalue.

Can someone please explain this to me?

```
const int N = 3;
void multiplyMatrix(const double a[][N], const double b[][N], const double c[][N])
{

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
            c[i][k] = a[i][0] * b[0][k] + a[i][1] * b[1][k] + a[i][2] * b[2][k];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{

    cout << "Enter matrix1: ";
    double m1[3][N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
            cin >> m1[i][k];
        }
    }

    cout << "Enter matrix2: ";
    double m2[3][N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
            cin >> m2[i][k];
        }
    }

    //have to initiliaze matrix to some value for math to work properly!!!
    double m3[3][N] = {};

    multiplyMatrix(m1, m2, m3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are passing array c as `const` and trying to update it.

Comment: @RamandeepPunia Ha. Thanks. I was using the exact function header that my textbook says to use, and never even thought about it. Makes perfect sense.

Comment: You would be better to declare `m1` etc as `double m1[N][N];` .  Your comment that you have to initialize `m3` is wrong - you only assign to `c`, you never read from it.

Comment: using `N` here is kinda pointless as your program will break horribly if N is changed from 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pass 3 matrices to my `multiplyMatrix` function. Matrices `a` and `b` are entered by the user, and `c` is the product of `a` and `b`. I am getting an error when assigning values to `c`.

> expression must be a modifiable Ivalue.

Can someone please explain this to me?

```
const int N = 3;
void multiplyMatrix(double a[3][3], double b[3][3],double c[3][3])
{

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
            c[i][k] = a[i][0] * b[0][k] + a[i][1] * b[1][k] + a[i][2] * b[2][k];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{

    cout << "Enter matrix1: ";
    double m1[3][N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
            cin >> m1[i][k];
        }
    }

    cout << "Enter matrix2: ";
    double m2[3][N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
            cin >> m2[i][k];
        }
    }

    //have to initiliaze matrix to some value for math to work properly!!!
    double m3[3][N] = {};

    multiplyMatrix(m1, m2, m3);

    return 0;
}
```

Just remove const and you are good to go.